# Calculating axle load in cargo container (pics are included)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, statics, moment

I'm current developing cargo loader software, but i have a little challenge with calculating load for each axle when a cargo is placed on container. I know that all axles will be affected (the nearest ones are the most affected ones of course), and I want to find approximately the value of each load. Here's example scenario in pictures:

[image]

I tried to find loads using balance rules taking each point as a pivot and calculating equation based on that position as below (EDIT: on the following figure in case 4 the 5th axle is pivot, I forgot to show it on figure):

[image]

[image]

But I think I have problem with above solution as I could not find F3, F4, F5 in special examples (putting "d" distance values from pivot - P.S in this last picture all "d"s are different distances from pivot in that case - so d3 in the first equation is not equal to d3 in second equation as these both have different distances to different pivots) - for easy calculation you can use Cramer's rule online calculator [here](http://matrix.reshish.com/cramer.php).

I tried to solve this problem with moment but I could not done as I'm not good in physics :( I could not find relations between different forces in that case, I had only F1*d1 + F2*d2 + F3*d3 = F4*d4 + F5*d5  and F1 + F2 + F3 + F4 + F5 = mg  ===> i got 5 unknowns but only 2 equations :(

So, i need your help! Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: I've not checked whether they are unique, but don't you have 6 equations?

Comment: And, are you familiar with basic linear algebra?

Comment: Yes, I've got 6 equations. But I'm not sure if this type of balance control is ok, because when I place numbers and try to find Determinant i'm getting 0, which means this system of linear equations is either inconsistent or has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Is that taking account that the pivot length isn't the same for every equation? i.e. are you solving for Fx*dx or Fx?

Comment: in the first equation F3*d3 = F3*(5+6) = F3*11 as the pivot in this case is first axle. But in the second equation F3*d3 = F3*6 (Distances are based on Figure-1). I try to find F1, F2, F3, F4 and F5. "d" distance values are known (P.S i've not provided a specific example because i'm trying to learn how it works but not to solve it).

Answer (score 1):

You basically have only two equations and five unknowns.  You have the total force on the five axles is the weight of the cargo and a moment equation that says the truck is not rotating.  The moment equations you are writing really amount to the same thing.  To do any more, you need to know the spring rate of each axle so you can write equations that say the bottom of the truck stays in a straight line.  For example, if axle 4 had zero spring rate, it would carry no weight.  If axles 3 through 5 all have the same spring rate, they will have almost the same load and you can consider them one axle with triple the rate and triple the load.

Comment: I was not taking into account spring rate of axles, but lets say all axles have the same spring rate. How should I treat each of them in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure it gives enough equations, but then the compression on each will be in proportion to the weight it carries.  Then if the straight line atop the wheels in the picture is straight and stays straight, there must be a linear relationship between wheel position and compression/weight carried.  I think this gives you the other equations you need.

Comment: If you think of a truck with just one rear axle, for a total of three, you still have two equations-one for total weight and one for moment.  You can imagine a distribution of loads positive on the front and rear wheels, negative on the center axle, that has no net force and no net moment.  The straight line is what fixes this mode and gives you enough equations.  I believe it will work with the three rear axles as well.  You need three more equations, but there are three modes to fix.

Comment: Mm then can I take F1 and F2 as one axle and force with F_12 and F3, F4 and F5 as second axle and force as F_345. Then solve equation of F_12 * d_12 = F_345 * d_345. Then after finding lets say F_345 again group it as F3 and F_45 if the cargo is between 3rd and 4th axles. Then I will find F_45 and etc. Is it right to proceed like this? (Of course it will not give me exact solution i know it)

Comment: I'm thinking that the modeling of suspension is critical to the correct result and unrealistic. I've seen tandem setups in which the rear axle clears the ground when the trailer is not loaded. The bogie tilted around its front axle. I presume this increases the weight on the front axle (better braking) and decreases wear on the other 2 tires.

Comment: I think you can just write straight line equations.  For example, since the rear three are equally spaced, let $x_3,x_4,x_5$ be the spring compressions.  We have $x_3-x_4=x_4-x_5$ if they started in line originally.  Now multiplying by the $k$'s you get a relation between the forces.  Similarly $x_2-x_3=3(x_3-x_4)$ and another involving $x_1$  That makes five equations in five unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the properties of the tires are the most critical factor in determining the distribution of loads in an overconstrained case like this. For software purposes I would repalce each tire with a spring (with dual tires having double the stiffness) and then consider the truck as two articulated rigid bodies (with pivot reaction forces between them).

This is directly solvable, but complex. The deflection of each spring (wheel) is a result of the small angular deflection (slope) of each rigid body coupled with the overall vertical deflection due to the load. Because of the non-linearity of the case where a wheel might lift (loss of contact) due to exesive bed slope this analysis can only be done with a simulation approach where spring force reactions are calculated from deflections and deflection changes are iterated from the inbalance of forces.

You cannot create an analytical solution to this that will give you reasonable results.

If you want to get a little fancier then the flexibility of the truck bed plays a role also as changes the slope of the bed according to the loading and reaction.

### Example Methodology with 1 DOF spring damper

To illustrate the process consider a single mass $m$ suspended by a compression only spring $k$ and a force $F$ is applied. The reaction force (spring force) $F_s$ could be trivially calculated from $F$ but in this case I just want to illustrate the steps for a computer program:

1. Set initial deflections to zero $x=0$
2. Calculate spring force $F_s = -k\, x$
3. If spring force is positive (tension) then set it to zero $F_s = {\rm min}(F_s,0)$
4. Sum of forces on body $\sum F = F+F_s$
5. Forces result in motion, but not like acceleration (to avoid dynamics) $\Delta x = C\,\sum F$ where $C$ is some simulation gain constant.
6. Change the deflections $x \rightarrow x + \Delta x$
7. If the change is small end here, otherwise goto step 2.

If you choose a gain factor $C$ to be too small then it will take a long time for the simulation to settle to a value, and if it is too bif then it will cause the iterations to be unstable alternating between two ever increasing values. The best value can come from experience, or if you know controls theory you can calculate it also.

For this case the simulation will end when $\Delta x \approx 0$ which happens when $F + F_s \approx 0$, or when $F = -F_s = k x \Rightarrow x = \frac{F}{k} $